# How would input the program at the bottom into the if-statement at the top?

Tags: java

So far what I have is the code below. Any input I type into the scanner returns my else statement, even if it is valid. For example, if I input "2222" I get the else statement, same for "222222222". Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program_04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;
        System.out.print("Enter a valid 4 character double literal: ");
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        s = stdIn.nextLine();
        if (isValid(s))
            System.out.println(s + " is a valid double literal");
        else 
        {
            System.out.print(s + " is not a valid double literal");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String s) {
        if (s.length() != 4)
            return false;

        String digits = "0123456789";
        if (s.charAt(0) != '+' && s.charAt(0) != '-' && digits.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) == -1) 
            return false;

        byte decimalCount = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '.')
                decimalCount++;
            else if (digits.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) == -1) 
                return false;
        }
        return decimalCount == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger to see why `isValid` is not returning what you expect.

Comment: your isValid is only returning true if decimalcount is 1 but for 2222 or 222222222 there are no decimals in the string so isValid is returning false.

Comment: In order for method `isValid` to return true, the method argument must contain a single decimal point and three digits or a single decimal point and two digits and a leading `+` or `-`. Try inputting the string `1.23` or `-1.2` or `-.25`

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I did not notice that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java regular expressions for this kind of task.
[Pattern Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(isValid("+222.2"));
        System.out.println(isValid("-22.2"));
        System.out.println(isValid("+2.22"));
        System.out.println(isValid("-2222"));
        System.out.println(isValid("+.222"));
        System.out.println(isValid("-22.2"));
    }

    private static boolean isValid(String string) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=^.{5}$)^(\\+|\\-)\\d+\\.(\\d+)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        boolean result = false;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            result = matcher.group(2).length() == 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```